# How to match an element in array? MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to check all the documents whose **specific field** is contained in an array.

For example I have the array

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

I want to match all the documents that has field `my_letter` equal to `a or b`.

I have the documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    my_letter:'d'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    my_letter:'a'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    my_letter:'b'
  }
]
```

I want the aggregation to return

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    my_letter:'a'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    my_letter:'b'
  }
]
```

I tried this in my `$match` pipeline

```
{
  $match: {
    _id: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $or: [
          { $eq: ["a"] },
          { $eq: ["b"] },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Of course it doesn't work. How would You suggest to complete the $match pipeline?

Comment: Hey, please edit your question and be more specific? I'm very confused by your question.

"I need to check all the documents whose specific field is contained in an array."

or 

"I want to match all the documents that has field my_letter equal to a or b."

Which one you want? Do you want to query the my_letter field or the _id field?

Please provide full examples of documents you have in the database and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: The real documents are too big, but basically I need to get all the users that has their _id in a given array. I tried with generic examples. Thank you btw

Comment: And what my_letter has to do with the _id? if the accepted answer is the correct one you are not even using _id filter

Comment: @LucasSoares It is just an example that can be applied doesn't matter the exact name. I just don't want to put myDB model here. The attribute name is not important. If it's *foo* or *_id* or *my_letter* is the same thing to me. Just wanted to abstract it. Sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  my_letter: {
    $in: [ "a", "b" ]
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gRq2B8kNoVq)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      my_letter: {
        $in: [ "a", "b" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4nzImvJS9U3)